# To pick at the scab - Is this a proper idiom

Tags: idioms, american-english

I couldn't find this particular idiom "to pick at the scab" in any of the famous dictionaries online like Cambridge or Macmillan. I could only find it on [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=to%20pick%20at%20the%20scab)

That makes me wonder if it's a correct idiom or not?

Comment: It's not incredibly common, but it would be understood.  Used more in colloquial situations, given the 'eewvvv' nature of the concept.

Comment: "To rub salt in the wound" would be a more common way to expresss this

Answer (score 8):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scab) doesn't consider it as a set phrase, but it gives an example of it used in the literal sense under the entry of ***scab*** as noun:

> a hard covering of dry blood that forms over a cut or sore:
>
> - Don’t ***pick at your scab***!

Urban simply states that it can be used figuratively, too. The phrase seems to be used more [recently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pick%20at%20the%20scab&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpick%20at%20the%20scab%3B%2Cc0). Here is an example found in *[A Widow's Words: Letters to My Beloved, By Cathy Penman](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n_pJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT296&lpg=PT296&dq=%22pick%20at%20the%20scab%22%20phrase&source=bl&ots=tY6SoE30LX&sig=ACfU3U0GucbL9UKVq8nh-i1Sdtt9gF9wGw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRqJnN2fbxAhWEZxUIHRkMAwkQ6AEwEXoECAcQAw)*:

> Similarly with a bereavement – ***don't 'pick at the scab'*** of the
> emotional wound, leave it alone to heal with time.

Answer (score 1):

Verbs and nouns that collocate, like *"have a shower"* or *"offer an apology"*, aren't considered idioms, so they don't get mentioned in dictionaries. The verb *"pick"* collocates with the noun "*scab"*, so it's natural to use them together, but a dictionary wouldn't list the collocation.

To *"pick a scab"* means to pull a scab off. To *"pick **at** a scab"* means to play with a scab over time, maybe pulling bits off, perhaps without focusing on it much, the way people twirl their hair or doodle.